# 400 error, in Flask application while loading a route with forms and database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am new to flask, and I am trying to add my forms objects so I can record them in my Database.

The problem is when I try to do something at the routes.py file I get a 400 error, and for the life of me I cant understand what is happening.

I also want to check if the record has already been added to the database before I commit the changes to the database.

Things are working ok at the database level as I have checked and created tables and headers in my models.py file, the forms.py file is also working fine, the problem occurs whenever I try to make it work at the routes.py file.

I am using a Blueprint factory model to develop this application as well.

Here is the Folders Structure

This is the folder structure

```
.
|
|- __init__.py
|- forms.py
|- models.py
|-routes.py
|-templates
|    |-clients-forms.html
|- util.py
```

****init****.py Contents:

```
    blueprint = Blueprint(
   'cml_blueprint',
    __name__,
    url_prefix='',
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static'
)
```

routes.py content:

```py
from flask import jsonify, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from flask_login import (
    current_user,
    login_required,
    login_user,
    logout_user
)

from app import db, login_manager
from app.cml import blueprint
from app.cml.forms import (
   ClientsForm, 
    RegisterForm,
    ComercialForm,
    SupplierForm,
    NonConformityForm,
    TestForm
)


from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from app import login_manager
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

@blueprint.route('/clients-forms.html', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def clients-forms():
               
    clients_form = ClientsForm(request.form) 

    id = request.form['id']
 

    registered_clients = Clients.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    if registered_clients:
        return render_template( 'clients-forms.html', 
                                msg='Already Registered',
                                success=False,
                                form=clients_form)


    registered_clients = ClientsForm(**request.form)
    db.session.add(registered_clients)
    db.session.commit()


    return render_template('clients-forms.html',
            form=cadastro_clientes_form )
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing what's in your `app.cml` file from which you are importing `blueprint`?

Comment: This is the folder structure
.
|
|- __init__.py
|- forms.py
|- models.py
|-routes.py
|-templates
|    |-clients-forms.html
|- util.py

the content is as follows


`'
blueprint = Blueprint(
        'cml_blueprint',
    __name__,
    url_prefix='',
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static'
)`

Comment: Do you also register the blueprint in init.py? (as in `app.register_blueprint(blueprint)`)

Comment: Yeah, everything is fine with every other route, except this one, It has something to do with the forms I am sure.
`
`# Here you can register the blueprints from other parts of the project 
def register_blueprints(app):
    for module_name in ('base', 'home', 'files', 'cml', 'cabotagem'):
        module = import_module('app.{}.routes'.format(module_name))
        app.register_blueprint(module.blueprint)`
`
`

Comment: What about changing the name of your function from `clients-forms` to `clients_forms`? Python interprets the subtraction and underscore signs differently.

Comment: Hey @PatrickYoder I think I found the issue. I wanst importing the DB models into the routes.py file, so the app didnt understand what it was requesting, perhaps that was the issue, wouldnt you agree? I actually havent changed the code yet but I will post my results.

Comment: Hey @PatrickYoder you were correct I changed to clients_forms and imported the DB models into my file! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix it was missing the import from the `models.py`

the file was lacking those imports and not runing on Development mode, so the only aswer I got back was a 400.

```py
from app.cml.models import RegisteredClients
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).